# Checkbox form validation not working

Tags: jquery, forms

I am trying to prevent form from validation if checkbox is not checked with following code:

```
<script>
$(function() {

    $("#form").submit(function(e) {
        console.log("test1");
        if(!$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')) {
            alert("Check the checkbox or you will die.");
            return false;
        }
        console.log("test2");
        return true;
    });
});
</script>
```

I don't know why my death threat doesn't appear. 
`console.log(test1)` is working. As well as `test2`.

Can you please guide me a little bit so I can see my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
!$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
```

With:

```
$("input:checked").length === 0
```

That way you are validating that there is at least one input checked in the DOM. I strongly recommend using an ID or CLASS to narrow the scope of the validation though.

Comment: it is working, thanks. 
also thanks for the comment about class/id selector
I will definitely use one.

Comment: No Problem, glad to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery selectors return a collection, not `true/false`. You need to test the size of the collection:

```
if ($(':checkbox:checked').length = 0) {
    alert("Check the checkbox or you will diet.");
    return false;
}
```